# Django : как заменить текст на урл?

Tags: python, django

Привет всем! Недавно начал изучать питон и джанго фреймворк. Пишу сейчас маленькую апликуху, которая стягивает твиты из твитера и постит мне на сайт их. Столкнулся с проблемой что иногда твиты содержат урлы,а они в браузере не отображаются как урлы. Незнаю как решить эту проблему =( может как-то методом из темплейта вызвать чтоб он обработал этот твит.. (правка):хотя нет, такого нельзя делать...

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь фильтром [urlize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) или urlizetrunc